# python selenium: how to use values already set by activity done manually via browser UI

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, profile

for sites that have difficult logins, I'm trying to manually login then use selenium to automate the rest of activity. I'm using **python**

1. via chrome browser UI, I manually created a user profile.
2. Then I manually login using that profile.
3. I then load the profile using selenium by,

> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>       options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/profile1");

but selenium doesn't seem to retain the already logged-in status

having done some tests (on other sites that don't have difficult logins) i see that my logged-in status is recognized only if I had initially logged in using selenium

how would i get selenium to use the already logged-in status that I did manually?

Comment: Selenium / chromedriver will create a new instance of chrome browser and that's why you won't be able to get logged in status. But I am curious why you want to do login manually but not using selenium?

Comment: i understand a new browser instance is launched, but history, cookies and settings should remain when associated to a profile. specific to my need, the profile is a bridge between doing things automated with selenium and manually via a browser UI. example, CAPTCHA logins can't be done using selenium. As mentioned above, when using a profile and logging-in using selenium then my previous login is recognized, but the previous login is not recognized by selenium if i had logged in manually. can i achieve my aim by loading the profile in a different way or different file like from the /tmp folder?